# Fill up remaining space using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I want the middle row to fill up whole browser just like any other websites. So even if there are few contents, I want the middle row to fill the entire space.

Here is the css

```
@import "compass/css3";

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;  

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main    { flex: 3 0px; }
  .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
  .main    { order: 2; }
  .aside-2 { order: 3; }
  .footer  { order: 4; }
}

body {
  padding: 2em; 
}
```

here is the html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zL26otcu/

Comment: the code is from: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ ? ;)

Comment: Yes 4lackof, it's from that site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a minor markup change and a few changes of your styles.

The most important change is to wrap your `main` and `aside` elements and give that `flex: 1`, making it always fill remaining space

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zL26otcu/3/)

```css
@import "compass/css3";

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  padding: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;             /*  include padding size within height  */
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;   /*  flow as column, no wrap  */
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  flex: 1;                            /*  fill remaining space  */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  padding: 10px;
  background: hotpink;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 3 0px;
  }
  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .main {
    order: 2;
  }
  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <article class="main">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </article>
    <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
    <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, taking a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:100vh` to `.main` class

https://jsfiddle.net/zL26otcu/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I duplicated what you are going for, adding `display: block` to `.main` should fix this. I've updated your jsfiddle and here's the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/zL26otcu/2/